# how to dynamically change the spaces using printf [using java]?

Tags: java, printf

I am working on an application that requires me to change the number of spaces dynamically.
Every time i need to increase the spaces by one. I know the logic behind it, but I couldn't find any documentation to help with the syntax.

```
System.out.printf("%3s", " ");
```

the code above is inside a nested loop, I would like the number 3 to be dynamic. the number needs to be a variable in order to accomplish what I need it to do.
how can I set the number before s to a  variable?

Answer (score 4):

Like:

```
int gap = 3;

System.out.printf("%" + gap + "s", " ");
```

Comment: Thanks, I though everything had to be in double quotes in order to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
String space = ""

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    space += " ";
    System.out.printf("%s", i + space + ",");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In, formating print output, Format specifiers begin with a percent sign (`%`) and end with a converter(`s`). The converter is a character indicating the type of argument to be formatted. In between the percent sign (%) and the converter you can have optional flags and specifiers(`width`, precision, sign).

```
long n = 461012;
System.out.format("%08d%n", n); // prints "00461012"
```

in the above example:

1. `d` is a converter specifying our target parameter `n` to be printed as decimal integer.
2. `08` is a flag: specifying the printed decimal integer should be eight characters in width, with leading zeroes as necessary.

Check the documentation : [Class Formatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) and [Formatting Numeric Print Output](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html)